# mysqli_sql_exception #1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' when inserting data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table named 'krs_jadwal'. The structure is like this:
table:
[image: table]

As you can see it doesn't have column 'id'. So, then I'm trying to insert data to this table but it telling me that 'unknown column 'id' in where clause' when I'm not even try to select or show the data.

**Here's the Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class Krs_Jadwal extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'krs_jadwal';
    protected $allowedFields = ['id_krs','id_jadwal'];
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\Krs_Jadwal;

class c_Krs_Jadwal extends BaseController
{
   
   protected $krs_jadwal;

   public function __construct(){
      $this->krs_jadwal = new Krs_Jadwal();
   }
   public function save(){
      $data = array_values(session()->get('krs'));
      for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) { 
        $this->krs_jadwal->save([
            'id_krs' => session()->get('id_krs'),
            'id_jadwal' => $data[$i]['id]
        ]);
      } 
   }
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: Maybe because you forgot the closed quote for `id` at this: `'id_jadwal' => $data[$i]['id]`

Comment: it probably typo but i already figure it out. Method save is used for table with column id in it yet my table didn't have it so i just need to insert it with another method by ci4. Thanks for answering